Can you sue a company for false advertisement even if you signed their terms and conditions?
I only have a broad general idea about false advertising so I am not sure if this scenario would be applicable for someone to be sued for false advertising.
If the buyer agreed that upon buying an item online that he/she is releasing the company(seller) for any claims that may arise, can the seller be not held accountable if the item is broken but was advertised in working condition? Is the seller protected because it is stated on the terms and conditions that the item is sold as is, even though the description of the item says it is working.

Where are the seller and the buyer? The law is not the same everywhere. It also matters somewhat if it is a consumer purchase or a business to business purchase. Consumers have different rights in most places.

How do you know that the item was broken when advertised, as opposed to being damaged in shipping?

england-and-wales
If the seller knows the item does not work but advertises that it works then that is false advertising.
However, it's unlikely the consumer would "sue for false advertising". They would sue to enforce their statutory rights, if the seller did not comply, and possibly complain about the false advertising (and unfair contract terms - see below) to Trading Standards and other authorities.
Consumers have statutory rights when buying goods - Consumer Rights Act 2015. Goods must be:

of satisfactory quality (section 9)
fit for purpose (section 10)
as described (section 11)

The law says every contract to supply goods is to be treated as including such a term (that's why they are also known as 'implied rights').
The seller can't enforce terms intended to avoid the effects of statutory rights. Such a term would be 'unfair' and therefore not binding on the consumer. Section 31:

A term of a contract to supply goods is not binding on the consumer to the extent that it would exclude or restrict the trader's liability arising under any of these provisions— [includes sections 9 to 11)

Section 31 is headed "Can a trader contract out of statutory rights and remedies under a goods contract?" and the concise answer is "generally: no".
Also, consumer contract terms which may be regarded as unfair, Schedule 2, Consumer Rights Act 2015:


A term which has the object or effect of inappropriately excluding or limiting the legal rights of the consumer in relation to the trader or another party in the event of total or partial non-performance or inadequate performance by the trader of any of the contractual obligations ...



False advertising is generally not something an individual can sue over
If there are laws about truth in advertising, then it is generally for the state to bring a case for breaching them, not any given individual.
Misrepresentation
A misrepresentation can be grounds for voiding a contract or abstaining damages. A false advertisement can be a misrepresentation.
Statutory Guarantees/Statutorily Implied Terms
Many jurisdictions impose statutory guarantees that sit beside contracts, or imply terms into contracts. Typically these include guarantees as to merchantability and fitness for purpose - a broken item (unless it was explicit sold as broken) is neither. Sometimes the contract can exclude these and sometimes it can’t; this may maybe an “as is” clause or “entire agreement” clause invalid. Such statutory protections usually only apply in B2C sales.
“As is” clauses
Particularly in second hand sales on a private basis, there is nothing wrong with selling an item “as is” and requiring the buyer to perform their own due diligence before entering the contract. As long as you don’t make a representation or refuse to answer a direct question. If the buyer doesn’t ask “does it work?”, there is not normally on obligation on the seller to disclose that it doesn’t.

Point 1 is not true in the US. The Lanham Act provides for civil enforcement.
